# Under what situation will np.genfromtxt read in an array of voids

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Trying to read a .Data file using np.genfromtxt

```
a = np.genfromtxt("u.data", dtype = [int, int, int, int], delimiter = '\t')
```

The output is an array of numpy voids. However, if I do not specify the data type, then the output is a normal array. I wonder what went wrong. I should also mention that if I do not specify the data type, numpy treats all the data automatically as float.

Comment: Look at `a.dtype`.  It's a structured array.

Comment: What does `dtype=int` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways of loading a simple csv

```
In [148]: txt = """1,2,3 
     ...: 4,5,6"""
```

default float:

```
In [149]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',')                                
Out[149]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

multiple int dtype - produces a structured array (read the docs):

```
In [150]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',dtype=[int,int,int])            
Out[150]: 
array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8')])
```

Structured with a mix of dtypes (more common case):

```
In [152]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',dtype=[int,float,'U10'])        
Out[152]: 
array([(1, 2., '3'), (4, 5., '6')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

All integer - 2d array like the float case:

```
In [153]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',dtype=int)                      
Out[153]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

`genfromtxt` docs are a bit long, but worth reading in full!

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I only put in dtype = int, it still outputs a structured array which is wired. Do you maybe know how to access individual elements in numpy.void?

Comment: Have you read about `structured arrays`?  Don't focus on that `numpy.void`.  That's not significant.  Look at the `dtype`.  If it is a compound dtype you need to access fields by name.  In my examples, `arr['f0']` etc.  But I'm surprised that the simple `int` still gives a structured array.  My example shows otherwise.